# Acquiring black and white stamen maps with get_map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to get the black and white version of a stamen map and its giving me the color version. I've tried downloading the map with get_map and get_stamenmap and both give me the color version regardless of whether I specify color as "bw" or "color". Any ideas or work arounds?

```
library(ggmap)
mapImage <- get_map(location = c(lon = -110.8, lat = 34.7),
                source = "stamen",
                maptype = "terrain",
                color = "bw",
                zoom = 7)
g <- ggmap(mapImage)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get black-and-white stamen maps, use `maptype = "toner"`. The color argument has no effect on stamen maps. You might also want a panel border around the plot. If so, use ggplot's `theme_bw()` or `theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black"))`.

```
library(ggmap)
mapImage <- get_map(location = c(lon = -110.8, lat = 34.7),
                source = "stamen",
                maptype = "toner",
                # color = "bw",
                zoom = 7)
ggmap(mapImage) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution was `get_stamenmap` with `maptype="toner".`

It is like `get_map` with `source="stamen"` speaks with a southern soft R and sloppy lisp dialect that stamen does not understand.

```
library(ggmap)
mapImage <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(-114,32,-107,37),
                    source = "stamen",
                    maptype = "toner",
                    zoom = 7)
ggmap(mapImage) +theme_bw()
```

did the trick for me (using Rstudio in Linux, potential bug)

Notice `bbox` as the alternative to `location` and `theme_bw()` as Sandy suggested

[image]